# How to forward UDP traffic between two interfaces using iptables

Tags: debian, iptables, routing

Good morning,

I need help to forward traffic in two interfaces on a debian12 server.
I have a server with two interfaces like this scheme:

INTERNET come on the ens224

```
  |
```

LAN go to the ens192

I want to redirect all the 3480/UDP traffic received by ens224 to ens192
I think to use this rule:

`iptables -A FORWARD -i ens224 -o ens192 -p udp --dport 3480 -d 10.67.1.101 -j ACCEPT`
do you think it's maybe ok?

thanks in advance for help.

Regards,

Comment: iptables doesn't route: it's here to filter what routing/forwarding can happen. So adding a rule in iptables allowing a specific routing/forwarding to happen doesn't magically make it happen. If the target is the system (rather than an actual routing/forwarding case where both source and target are remote), you need NAT (DNAT) too. NAT doesn't route either, but will change the routing stack's vision of what to do and lead to routing in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you have traffic arriving on the interface `ens224` bound for that machine, and you want to forward that traffic to another machine attached to the interface `ens192`, you can do that with a pair of NAT rules. The first rewrites the destination address so the packet can be forwarded to your target, and the second rewrites the source address so the target machine knows where responses should be sent. This second rule isn't always necessary, if the target machine would already route packets back in the right direction.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d A.A.A.A -p udp --dport 3480 -j DNAT --to-destination B.B.B.B
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d B.B.B.B -p udp --dport 3480 -j MASQUERADE
```

Where `A.A.A.A` is the machine receiving the traffic you want to forward, and `B.B.B.B` is the target machine you want to forward that traffic to